# Where is my intent error coming from?

Tags: java

Everything in my program seems to work fine, but for some odd reason whenever it gets to the input section where you choose multiply or divide it then terminates the program as if it had finished.

What's wrong with this?

I've tried changing `if(Choice.equals(Multiply))`
to "`Multiply`" and the same for the other as well.

But no luck.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class APJAVAPROGRAM {


    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner numberinput = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner stringinput = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Input a numerator >>>");              // inputs first Numerator
    double Numerator = numberinput.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Input a Denominator >>>");            // Inputs first denominator
    double Denominator = numberinput.nextDouble();


    System.out.print("Input a second numerator >>>");               //Inputs second Numerator
    double Numerator2 = numberinput.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Input a second Denominator >>>");         // Inputs second denominator
    double Denominator2 = numberinput.nextDouble();


    System.out.println("Your entered fractions are " + Numerator + "/" + Denominator + "  and "+ Numerator2 + "/" + Denominator2);
    // Will print out the entered fractions

    System.out.println("What would you like to do with these?");          //asks user what should be done
    System.out.print("Multipy, Divide, Add, or Subtract >>>");
    String Choice = stringinput.nextLine();                               

    double Multiply = Numerator * Numerator2;                              
    double Multiply2 = Denominator * Denominator2;
    if(Choice.equals("Multiply"))
    {
    System.out.println(Multiply + "/" + Multiply2 + " Is your answer.");
    // If the input is multiply it will do as such
    }
    else    
    {
    double Divide = Numerator * Denominator2;
    double Divide2 = Numerator2 * Denominator;
    if(Choice.equals("Divide"))
    System.out.println(Divide + "/" + Divide2 + " Is your answer.");




    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: i used the one in eclipse and it didn't find anything

Comment: I just dumped your code verbatim in my IntelliJ inside a `main()` method and it ran fine.  Please post a reproducible sample if you have one.

Comment: When it gets down to what you want it to do, it just terminates after that. But i cant find any error

Comment: Style hint: in Java variable (and method) names are typically started with lower case letter. Class names are typically started with upper case. Following the style generally used with a language makes it easier for others to read your code, and helps you understand other code too (since you're then used to the common style).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.equals(Object obj)` is case sensitive, if you type in "Multiply" or "Divide" with a capital letter it runs correctly.

Use the `.equalsIgnoreCase(Object obj)` for String to String comparison, ignoring case considerations

Comment: Thank you so much ive been stuck on this for like two hours

Answer (score 0):

I have just run you code and that's all ok. Here the input/output I got:

```
Input a numerator >>>1
Input a Denominator >>>2
Input a second numerator >>>3
Input a second Denominator >>>4
Your entered fractions are 1.0/2.0  and 3.0/4.0
What would you like to do with these?
Multipy, Divide, Add, or Subtract >>>Multiply
3.0/8.0 Is your answer.
```